# Python-pyqt: how to close a dialog and go back to terminal launching it with a button

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, gnome

i run a pyqt script in terminal#1, then i switch to other workspace. with time passing, the script launches a dialog with a button then. now i want to push the button which could close the dialog and bring me back to the terminal#1. is there any possible way?

notice that now i'm in another workspace. i have plenty of terminals opening, finding out which one launches this script is dull. maybe the procedure should record the father window and does two step action: switch workspace, pop the father window up. i have no idea...

simplified code:

```
class MyWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton("&hahaha")
        self.connect(self.button, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self, SLOT("accept()"))
    def accept(self):

        #what can i do here?

time.sleep(5)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
notify = MyWindow(message)
notify.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: It's an odd wish. Programs usually don't behave like that, it may confuse users. Terminals are not standardized, e.g. in Guake the terminal window only becomes visible when user presses the hot key. It's not possible to find and activate the terminal window without writing custom workarounds for all possible options. Why do you want to switch to the terminal? Maybe you should make the terminal window a part of your application. Or maybe you can do your whole task in a more standard way without that particular step.